# How can I set a a footer with page number in cordova-plugin-html2pdf?

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to create a PDF in a Cordova application using the Cordova-plugin-html2pdf. I don't know how to put a footer on every page of the generated PDF.

This is the code I have now for the creation of PDF:

```
var htmlDoc = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/css/main.css'></head><body>"+document.getElementById("myDocument").innerHTML+"</body></html>";


 pdf.htmlToPDF({
       data: htmlDoc,
       documentSize: "A4",
       landscape: "portrait",
       type: "base64",
 },
 sucess, error);
```

How can I add the footer for showing page number in the generated PDF?